# Dashed double arrow--tikzcd

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I want to  draw the following graph using tikzcd.

[image]
How should I modify the following？

```
\begin{tikzcd}
X\ar[Rightarrow, d] \\
Y\ar[d, bend left, "g"]\ar[d, bend right, "f"swap]\\
Z
\end{tikzcd}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As always in the site, please provide a full but minimal self contained example that others can copy and test as is. Here you have only provided a sniplet and thus others have to add document and class in order to even test the code. The code  gives the correct image after I edited the formatting and fixed the ``\\``

Comment: @daleif Thank you.

Comment: See the edit of my comment, your code works just fine

Comment: I would probably add `,pos=0.51` to both of the bendy arrows to move the `f` and `g` a bit

Comment: @daleif Sure and thanks. It looks good now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add `dashed` option:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[labels={font=\scriptsize, pos=0.51}]
X \ar[d, Rightarrow, dashed]     \\ % <---
Y \ar[d, bend  left, "g"]
  \ar[d, bend right, "f" ']     \\
Z 
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @daleif This is not necessary. The code is great.

Comment: @daleif, you are right! Corrected.

Comment: @Jian you did ask for a dashed arrow, which I did not provide in my comments but Zarko did in this answer